# Create Dropdown menu in Shiny - R using tags

Tags: html, r, drop-down-menu, shiny

I know using following code I can create normal dropdown menu in shiny,

```
selectInput("Input1", "Choose you Input:", choices = c('a1'='1','b2'='2'))
```

which will create following dropdown

[image]

But I am using **conditionalPanel** and for which I am populating kind of **inline dropdownmenu**s something like this

[image]

I am using following code to generate these menus.

```
conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==3",
                     div(style="display:inline-block",
                         tags$label('Menu1', `for` = 'Sample'), 
                         tags$select(id = 'Sample', class="input-small")),
                     div(style="display:inline-block",
                         tags$label('Menu2', `for` = 'Sample1'), 
                         tags$select(id = 'Sample1', class="input-small")))
```

My problem is **I am not able to add items to these dropdown menu**. I tried values or options, but that did't change anything.

I hope I have provided enough information, let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can supply a list of tags to `tagList`. The tags you need are `option` tags with `value` attributes You can construct these using `mapply`

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    numericInput('n', 'Enter 3 for condition', 3, 0, 10),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.n==3",
                     div(style="display:inline-block",
                         tags$label('Menu1', `for` = 'Sample'), 
                         tags$select(id = 'Sample', class="input-small",
                                     tagList(mapply(tags$option, value = 1:10, 
                                                    paste0(letters[1:10], 1:10), 
                                                    SIMPLIFY=FALSE)))
                     ),
                     div(style="display:inline-block",
                         tags$label('Menu2', `for` = 'Sample1'), 
                         tags$select(id = 'Sample1', class="input-small",
                                     tagList(mapply(tags$option, value = 1:2, 
                                                    paste0(letters[1:2], 1:2), 
                                                    SIMPLIFY=FALSE)))
                     )
    )
    , textOutput("cond")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$cond <- renderText({
      if(input$n == 3){
        paste0("Sample value selected =", input$Sample, " Sample1 value selected =",input$Sample1)
      }
    })
  }
))
```

Of course you can just use `selectInput` inside the `div` for example:

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    numericInput('n', 'Enter 3 for condition', 3, 0, 10),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.n==3",
                     div(style="display:inline-block",
                         selectInput("Sample", "Choose you Input:", choices = c('a1'='1','b2'='2'))
                     ),
                     div(style="display:inline-block",
                         tags$label('Menu2', `for` = 'Sample1'), 
                         tags$select(id = 'Sample1', class="input-small",
                                     tagList(mapply(tags$option, value = 1:2, 
                                                    paste0(letters[1:2], 1:2), 
                                                    SIMPLIFY=FALSE)))
                     )
    )
    , textOutput("cond")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$cond <- renderText({
      if(input$n == 3){
        paste0("Sample value selected =", input$Sample, " Sample1 value selected =",input$Sample1)
      }
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: It worked. Can you explain what SIMPLIFY does? I tried to keep it true but in that case items didn't populated... Also any idea how can I make this menu look like normal shiny selectInput menu.

Comment: `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` stops `mapply` from creating an array from the output and leaves the output as a list. What does the normal shiny `seleectInput` menu look like?

Comment: You can of course just put the `selectInput` statements inside your `div` and keep your `divs` inline....